# Trying to insert kernel module noop-iosched.ko results in segmentation fault

Tags: linux, linux-kernel, kernel, kernel-module

I made it so that I would compile the noop-iosched.c as a kernel module. However when I try to do `insmod noop-iosched.ko`, it results in a Segmentation Fault. 
I don't understand why this is happening. When I list the modules, it appears there. However, if I try to remove it, it gives me an error, saying the module "is in use". And is listed as being used by '1'.

Link to see the noop-iosched.c [Link](http://www.cs.fsu.edu/~baker/devices/lxr/http/source/linux/block/noop-iosched.c?v=2.6.25#L20)
Any help I can get, I will really appreciate it.

Answer (score 1):

I found the solution to the problem. Sometimes Segmentation Faults when inserting the kernel module will occur if the `MODULE_LISCENSE` is missing. Mine was not exactly missing, however after editing it, it worked and now I do not have Segmentation Fault and my module works fine.